# Unable to locate app-routing.module.ts in ionic

Tags: ionic4

I have installed ionic frame work and created a project called sudo ionic start everything is good so far i have choosed ionic with a side bar project and following the tutorial over here https://www.sitepoint.com/ionic-4-angular-build-app/ And i have done a couple of reserch but all the documents are actually assuming that the src/app/app-routing.module.ts File is already there any help is really appriciatable i have checked there official documentation in at that also they are assuming this file is already there.

My Ionic version

CLI PRO 4.0.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it if I use

```
type--angular
```

that file will be there other ways that file won't be there. This is same for 6 and 4 as well